# Virtuemart - Products are in source but are not visible in page

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am a newbie in Joomla and trying my luck in Virtuemart.

I published some products in http://anuskincare.com/anuskincare/ under 'products' but I see no products at all. However, I can see them inside page-source. I suspect its a template problem. Please share your valuable comments and opinions on how this can be fixed.

Thanks a ton

Comment: try clearing your cache and load jquery in the head section "/anuskincare/cache/js-32eee6e625ad213ac7938098844d8ecb.php" <--might be the case of error

Answer (score 0):

You definately have a problem loading jQuery.  A very likely possibility is that your virtuemart configuration isn't specifying to load the jquery library.  Try changing those settings and see if that then loads the library for you.

If that doesn't do it, you'll see that the first JS error is: `jQuery is not defined` - If you're not using Firebug, I'd start by getting that, then visiting the JED and seeing if any of the [jQuery Plugins](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts) will assist with the problem.